# sql-server How to divide two tables?

Tags: sql-server

I want to get remainder after dividing two tables .
Example:
table1 contains

```
name   roll city  
gran     1  mumbai  
raj      2  kolkata  
mahesh   3  delhi
```

Table 2 contains

```
roll   
2  
3
```

Then the output should be

```
name  city  
raj   kolkata  
mahesh  delhi
```

update: I don't want to get the output after supplying column names. I want the result to come out after filtering only the one column

Comment: Do you mean Relational Division? The result you specified is not the result of a relational division. It looks more like a join to me. Could you explain the logic behind your example please.

Comment: The question is not clearly stated.  What columns are defined for your two tables?  I assume you are saying Table 1 has four rows and Table 2 has three rows, and the output reflects matching three of Table 1's rows to rows in Table 2.  But it isn't clear if these tables are defined to contain a single column, say of type varchar, or if perhaps Table 1 has three columns and Table 2 has one column.  Also you should clarify if there is at most one row in Table 1 for each row in Table 2, or if the same row in Table 2 could match more than one row in Table 1.

Comment: Yes Its true i want to join tables. you can understand it better if you create two circle figures and supply the data.

Comment: SQL / relational operations generally assume that the attribute names are specified or fixed at design-time. There is no standard method in SQL that does what you want. I think you would have to generate the code to do it dynamically at runtime. How is it that you don't know in advance what columns you want in your query?

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
select name,city from table_1 where
roll in (select roll from table_2)
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but i wished to get the output after joining two tables without supplying column names

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a nested `SELECT` when you can just use an `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT name, city 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
  ON table1.roll = table2.roll
```

Comment: i wished if the output could come without supplying column names

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, city from table1
where roll in (select roll from table2)
```